# Controlling Multiple I/O Devices

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, power-electronics, multiplexer

How to manage multiple Input(Sensors like Temperature, Humidity, etc..) and output(like motors, relays, etc..) devices connected to a micro controller(Arduino UNO). There are more I/O devices present than the I/O Pins. I am thinking to use demultiplexer for controlling the outputs and multiplexer for Inputs, which are connected to the micro ontroller. But not sure how to connect them(micro controller, multiplexer/demultiplexer, Input/Output Devices). So, did I choose the right choice. if yes, how to connect those. if not, what is the alternative solution.

Comment: Connect the micro controller to the Input/Output Devices using a Multiplexer/Demultiplexer.

Comment: i think that your question has been answered many times on the web ... look for tutorials

Comment: a mux can be used for input ... for instance, a 1 of 8 mux would have 8 inputs, 1 output and 3 address pins ... setting the address pins to a value would connect one of the inputs to the output

Comment: This question is not answerable as written.  Show us a schematic of your circuit and maybe you'll get some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your choice is right. You can manage more inputs and outputs with MC14051B, MC14052B, MC14053B. Link of the data-sheet is- https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC14051B-D.PDF 
[image]
[image: Truth Table]

To increase output voltage- [image: Connection]

To decrease input voltage use resistors according to the voltage divider rule.

Comment: I am new to these can you please explain the circuit above.

Comment: Do I need to use any pull down registers in mux inputs and outputs ?